# when i run code in emulator in android studio this message appear

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, android-emulator, flutter-test

ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. INFO | Android emulator version 31.1.4.0 (build_id 7920983) (CL:N/A)

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue before, then I removed **hardware-qemu.ini.lock** and **multiinstance.lock** on **.android/avd/'AVDNAME.avd directory'** and it resolved my issue.